# Update SQL Server database from excel

Tags: sql, excel, sql-update

I'm trying to develop a stock market evaluation program in VB.NET. For this purpose, I have an Excel sheet (name is price) with 120 rows for setting price and volume movements.

Like this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]:

I imported this sheet into SQL Server via Management Studio without any problem. But I have to update database everyday. I have to delete the first row and add a new row at the end of the database and enter new price data.

It is very simple to update excel sheet but I don't know how I can update database from this Excel sheet?

Thank you very much for everybody.

Comment: For this, I would create a VSTO Excel add-in. I made one that creates a SQL database table from a tab (data included) so what you're asking is surely possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do this.  My preference would be SSIS.  For two reasons.  First, integrating data from flatfiles (like Excel) is what it is made for.  Second, it can be easily scheduled.  So, it meets both your needs.

Look [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/moving-data-from-excel-to-sql-server-10-steps-to-follow/) for an SSIS tutorial on loading data from Excel to SQL

[image]

And look [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/220/scheduling-ssis-packages-with-sql-server-agent/) for a tutorial on how to schedule a daily SSIS package in SQL server.

[image]

Good luck!